# Parsing an XML Like String in JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm trying to parse a String which is XML like, and looks like this:

```
<note>
 <user>Username 1</user>
 <notes>Notes user wrote</notes>
</note>
<note>
 <user>Username 2</user>
 <notes>Notes user wrote</notes>
</note>
```

I'm a little bit confused with how to use the JQuery XML parser, I guess i'm used to SQL programming to access data.

What I want to do is print out the note based on the user name

so in SQL that'd be "SELECT notes FROM note WHERE user='Username 1'"

How do you do a selection like that in the JQuery XML Parser?

Edit what i'm trying:

**For some reason this keeps returning Null:**

```
 var xml = '<url>urlofpage1</url><notes>These notes should load!</notes>';
 var $xml = $(xml);

var $notes = $xml.find('url')
                 .filter(function() { return $(this).text() == 'urlofpage1' })
                 .closest('notes');

console.log('$notes: ', $notes.html());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'd want a jQuery object:

```
var xml = '<note><user>Username 1</user><notes>Notes user wrote</notes></note><note><user>Username 2</user><notes>Notes user wrote</notes></note>';
var $xml = $(xml);
```

Then you could use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) and the [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to find the particular `<user>` you wanted and then [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to go back up to the `<note>`:

```
var $notes = $xml.find('user:contains("Username 1")').closest('note');
```

For example (run with the console open): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3Yqqu/

You have to be careful with the `:contains` selector though as:

> The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof.

Hence the `user:contains` (a narrow search) followed by `closest` to go back up. You might want to add an extra [filtering step](http://api.jquery.com/filter) if you're looking for strict equality rather than something LIKEish:

```
var $notes = $xml.find('user')
                 .filter(function() { return $(this).text() == 'Username 1' })
                 .closest('note');
```

And an example of this (console open again please): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/fYNXx/

The thinking is similar to SQL in that you're working with sets most of the time. However, you often chain things together more in the sense of shell pipeline than nested queries, sub-selects, and derived tables.

Comment: Interesting good to know, i'll try it and see how it turns out, looks like I need to learn more about XML

Comment: Just tried it, for some reason I can't get $notes to print out as anything except for [object Object] any idea why?

Comment: @Talon: That's because it is an object rather than a string. Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/F4UUh/

Comment: I'm trying this:

var xml = '<url>urlofpage1</url><notes>These notes should load!</notes>';
var $xml = $(xml);

var $notes = $xml.find('url')
                 .filter(function() { return $(this).text() == 'urlofpage1' })
                 .closest('notes');
                 
console.log('$notes: ', $notes.html()); 

But it keeps returning Null

Comment: I also tried note.toSource() to try and print out the entire object and it seems to not print out properly.

Comment: @Talon: You'd want `filter` for `'<url>urlofpage1</url><notes>These notes should load!</notes>'` as `find` looks at the descendants but you're looking at siblings.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean? I thought it already is using filter.

Comment: @Talon: `$xml.find('url')...`, the `find` won't work in that context as it will be starting one level too deep.

Comment: I included an outer wrapper note like this and it still does the same thing:
e.g.
<note>
 <url>url of page 1</url>
 <notes>These are the notes of page 1</notes>
</note>

Comment: Maybe post a new question, this comment thread is getting a bit long.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 1**
mu is too short's answer seems much cleaner, I'd go with that

**EDIT 2**
That wasn't quite right. This works; you can see the example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/XLyGe/).

```
function getNotesByUser(xml, username){
    var notes
    $(xml).siblings('note').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('user').text() == username){
            notes = $(this).find('notes');
            return false; //break early
        }
    });
    return notes;
}

var xml = "<note><user>Username 1</user><notes>Notes user wrote</notes></note><note><user>Username 2</user><notes>Notes user2 wrote</notes></note>";

alert(getNotesByUser(xml, "Username 1").text());
alert(getNotesByUser(xml, "Username 2").text());
```

Comment: But `:contains` can be tricky to use so your version is worth seeing. I'd probably use `find('user')` instead of `siblings` to go straight to them and then `closest('note')` to go back up.

Comment: Thanks. My first attempt wasn't quite right - without a tag enclosing `note`s, `children` obviously doesn't work. And I don't know what I was thinking when I used `first` instead of `find`!

Comment: There's also `filter` as a sort of "`find` that goes sideways".

Comment: I remember now :) A little rusty after 3 months of doing nothing!